# Loading data segment of already loaded shared library

Tags: gcc, ld, elf

For global offset table to work, GOT must be at a fixed location from text segment. Now assume that a program needs a shared library. Assume also that the shared library is already loaded by the OS for some other process. Now for our program, since text section of shared library is already loaded, it just needs to load data segment. The shared library text section is mapped back to the virtual address of our process. But what if there is already some data/text or whatever at the fixed offset from the virtual address of our shared library. How does the dynamic linker resolve that conflict? One approach would be to leave R_386_GOTPC in the text section till load time and let the dynamic linker change it the new offset. Is this how it is done in practice.

Answer (score 0):

On GNU, even the same DSO is mapped at different addresses in different processes.  No data at all is shared between them.  This means that the GOT is just private data (like `.data`), and is initialized at load time with the proper addresses (either stubs or the proper function addresses with `BIND_NOW`).

(This assumes that `prelink` is not in use, which is somewhat broken anyway.)